# Facebook wall post error : The user hasn't authorized the application to

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

got error when i want to  post  text in facebook wall .

this is my code

```
function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
              alert('logged out');
              });
}
```

// i am able to login successful . using this method .

```
function login() {

    FB.login(function(response) {
             if (response.authResponse) {
             var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
             alert('Access Token = ' + access_token);
             alert("Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ");
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
             } else {
             alert("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
             }


             },{
             scope: 'publish_actions',
             return_scopes: true
             });




}
```

// here i call this method to post the text in FB wall . and i am getting status logged in a  but i got error .

```
function SubmitPost() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                      if (response.status == 'connected') {

                      alert('logged in');
                      try {

                      var wallPost = {
                      message: "post in fb" ,
                      picture: '',
                      link: '',
                      name: 'test app posted in your wall',
                      caption: '',
                      description: ('Test description')
                      };
                      FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost, function (response) {
                             if (!response || response.error) {
                             /*action*/
                             alert('Message could not be Posted.');
                             alert(response.error.message);
                             console.log(response.error.message);
                             } else {
                             /*action*/
                             alert('Message Posted successfully.');
                             }
                             });


                      }
                      catch (err) { alert('SubmitPost: ' + err);
                      }


                      } else {
                      alert('not logged in');
                      }
                      });


}
```

Comment: Post the `scope`/permissions. You're having an issue with permissions which are set using `scope` so why aren't you worried in the slightest what your scope actually is. Secondly learn to use breakpoints. This is simple but you don't know how to debug it. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index#debugging-javascript

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#handling

Answer (score 0):

Please check your host URL matches with the URL given in the Facebook app "Website URL". Both should be exactly same.

If your are not added in facebook Website URL which reside under your App setting , then you can create this by hitting to "Add Platform" .

Steps to get website URL for the Facebook application:

1] If you are not created facebook app , To create Goto 
      https://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf

2] Select **Apps** -> **Create a new app**

3] Fill the app details in the popup. Click on **Create App**

4] You will be redirected to **dashboard** page of your newly created application.
   [ Note down the ***AppID***]

5] Then click on "**Settings**" present at left side and then click on  **Add Platform**

6] Choose "**Website**" from the popup menu.

7] Now you can find 2 fields : Site URL and Mobile Site URL.
   Here you should fill your website URL where your are calling facebook SDK.

Comment: can you tell me steps how to do this .i dont have idea

Comment: Follow the steps [1to 7] as I have mentioned above.